# Initializing async rest api's instead of doing it in a constructor -c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have to fetch some data through rest calls and cache them so that it can be used in the SDK i am working
Just wanted to make sure if this is a correct approach or would like to know if it can be done in any better way

```
public class Library {

    private bool isInitialized;
    public Library(...dependencies) {}

    public async Task InitializeAsync() {
        if (!isInitialized) {
            var data1 = await "api call";
            var data2 = await "api call2";

            isInitialized = true
            //cache them
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, it seems okay. Just take care about thread safety if you need (because current implementation isn't).

Comment: I think, it's better to ask it on codereview

Comment: @Posio ,I think we couldn't add async code in the body of lock,how to address that

Comment: It would be ideal to use "Ghost Objects" design pattern in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Lazy<>` which has settings for thread safety.

public class Library {

```
private Lazy<somedata> _someData;
public Library(...dependencies) 
{
    _someData = new Lazy<somedata>(() => initialise and store data);
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    var somedata = _someData.Value; <--- this will initialise the first time it's used
}
```

}